# Define a function called information that takes user input

Tags: python, function, input

How can I define a function called information that takes user input, the variables are (*name, birth_year, fav_color, and hometown*).  It should return a tuple of these variables in this order.

Comment: write like def information(*args):

Answer (score 2):

This is probably what you're looking for

```
def information():
    name = input("Insert your name.\n")
    birth_year = input("Insert your year of birth.\n")
    fav_color = input("Insert your favourite color.\n")
    hometown = input("Insert your hometown's name.\n")

    return (name, birth_year, fav_color, hometown)
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Comment: @pppery. In this case, I'd say it's pretty self explanatory

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```py
def information():
    data = ()
    name = input('Enter your name: ')
    yob = input('Enter your year of birth: ')
    fav_color = input('Enter your favourite colour: ')
    hometown = input('Enter your hometown: ')

    data = (name, yob, fav_color, hometown)
    return data
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `input` inside a function.

```
def info():
    name=input("enter name")
    birth_year=input("DOB")
    fav_color=input("fav color")
    home_town=input("Home town")
    return (name,birth_year,fav_color,home_town)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
>>> info()
enter namech3ster
DOB31st feb
fav colorblack
Home townxxxxx
('ch3ster', '31st feb', 'black', 'xxxxx')
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is quite simple in fact:

```
def information():
    name = input("what is our name?")
    birth_year = input("what year were you born?")
    fav_color = input("what is your favourite colour?")
    hometown = input("what is your hometown?")
    return name, birth_year, fav_color, hometown
```

you can then later run that function by writing `information()`. The `input()` function behaves as usual, when it is inside a function. So for this it is quite simply just a matter of placing the `input()` command inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
def information():
    name = input("Name: ").strip()

    # if you want to get birth year as an int, else use it without int.
    birth_year = int(input("Birth Year: "))

    fav_color = input("Favourite Color: ").strip()

    hometown = input("Hometown's name: ").strip()

    return (name, birth_year, fav_color, hometown)
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def information(name, birth_year, fav_color, hometown):
    return name, birth_year, fav_color, hometown
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
 def information (name, birth_year, fav_color, hometown):

     return (name, birth_year, fav_color, hometown)

 info_tups=information("Rupak",1996,"Blue","Dhaka")

 print(info_tups)
```

Comment: Please avoid code-only answers and post a short explanation why your code works.

Answer (score -1):

```
def function(name, birth_year, fav_color, hometown):
    return (name, birth_year, fav_color, hometown)
```

Here the returned value is a tuple of the input params for that function.

Comment: The function you provided doesn't answer the original question - it doesn't have user input and there's really no reason for a function that uses user input to have any arguments.